# Sending Json data to server, from a file, periodically using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there any $.get() equivalent in python2.7 through which I could send data, from a file (upon being modified), to a server?
I have used cronjobs to perform these kinds of things, but here I do not want to use it.

Comment: If you just need to send get requests the requests library might be helpful: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Comment: @kingkupps - Thank you  very much, Sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the first you need to read a string from your file:

```
with open("your file", "r") as f:
    data = f.read()
```

then you should convert string `data` to `json`:

```
import json
json = json.loads(data)
```

then by `requests` module send it to your server:

```
import requests
resp = requests.get(url="your url", params=json) #you can use post instead of get
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sir. This is very nice of you to post all the relevant stuff.

Comment: Any idea, how to send a request to the server every 30 secs, am not wishing to use cronjobs.

Comment: You can use from ‘apscheduler’ module for that.

Comment: Thank a lot again, Sir. Visited the link, that actually is what I need.